# most efficient way to select three lists from a list of lists such that the number of unique elements in all lists combined is larger than a threshold

Tags: python, list, selection

What is the most efficient way to find out wether it's possible to select three lists from a list of lists such that the number of unique elements in all lists combined is larger than some specific number? The best solution i can come up with is brute force:

```
def maximum_number_of_unique_elements(mylist, threshold):
    for a in range(len(mylist)):
        for b in range(a,len(mylist)):
            for c in range(b,len(mylist)):
                if len(set(mylist[a] + mylist[b] + mylist[c])) >= threshold:
                    return True
   return False
```

Example:

```
l = [[0,1,2],[0,1],[0,3,6],[3,7],[4,7]]
t = 7
```

`maximum_number_of_unique_elements(l,t)` returns `True`, because by selecting lists `0,2,4` a set with numbers `0,1,2,3,4,6,7` is created.

Comment: Don't name a variable `list` that is the buitlin name of the list constructor

Comment: I don't know if it's more efficient, but you can use `itertools.combinations` to iterate over all possible choices of 3 lists.

Comment: Depends on the data.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution would use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, that allows to set the amount of list to use without changing the code (not a `for` loop per list)

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain

def maximum_number_of_unique_elements(values, threshold, nb_list=3):
    for parts in combinations_with_replacement(values, r=nb_list):
        if len(set(chain.from_iterable(parts))) >= threshold:
            return True
    return False
```

---

With `combinations_with_replacement` each element can be repeated, use `combinations` to get unique elements

```
print(list(combinations('ABC', r=2)))
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]

print(list(combinations_with_replacement('ABC', r=2)))
# [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'C')]
```

Comment: Seems a bit slower, at least on that only input they bothered to provide (benchmark in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

A few optimizations:

```
def maximum_number_of_unique_elements(mylist, threshold):
    sets = list(map(set, mylist))
    n = len(sets)
    for i, one in enumerate(sets):
        for j in range(i, n):
            two = one | sets[j]
            thresh = threshold - len(two)
            for third in sets[j:]:
                if len(third - two) >= thresh:
                    return True
    return False
```

Benchmark results:

```
 7.68 us  original
 8.06 us  azro
 4.49 us  Manuel

 7.77 us  original
 8.01 us  azro
 4.46 us  Manuel

 7.78 us  original
 7.85 us  azro
 4.48 us  Manuel
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain

def original(mylist, threshold):
    for a in range(len(mylist)):
        for b in range(a,len(mylist)):
            for c in range(b,len(mylist)):
                if len(set(mylist[a] + mylist[b] + mylist[c])) >= threshold:
                    return True
    return False

def azro(values, threshold, nb_list=3):
    for parts in combinations_with_replacement(values, r=nb_list):
        if len(set(chain.from_iterable(parts))) >= threshold:
            return True
    return False

def Manuel(mylist, threshold):
    sets = list(map(set, mylist))
    n = len(sets)
    for i, one in enumerate(sets):
        for j in range(i, n):
            two = one | sets[j]
            thresh = threshold - len(two)
            for third in sets[j:]:
                if len(third - two) >= thresh:
                    return True
    return False

def benchmark(*args):
    solutions = original, azro, Manuel
    number = 10 ** 5
    for _ in range(3):
        for solution in solutions:
            t = min(repeat(partial(solution, *args), number=number)) / number
            print('%5.2f us ' % (t * 1e6), solution.__name__)
        print()
benchmark([[0,1,2],[0,1],[0,3,6],[3,7],[4,7]], 7)
```